# exclude words those may or may not end with slash

Tags: language-agnostic, rg

I am trying to exclude certain words from dictionary file.

```
# cat en.txt
test
testing
access/p
batch
batch/n
batches
cross

# cat exclude.txt
test
batch

# grep -vf exclude.txt en.txt
access/p
cross
```

The words like "testing" and "batches" should be included in the results.

```
expected result:
testing
access/p
batches
cross
```

Because the word "batch" may or may not be followed by a slash "/". There can be one or more tags after slash (n in this case). But the word "batches" is a different word and should not match with "batch".

Comment: `grep -w` seems to require whole word matches, have you tried that?

Comment: Can you have a line like `foo/batch` in `en.txt`? If so should it be output or not given your posted `exlude.txt`? Can `exclude.txt` contain any single letters like `n` such as occur in `batch/n`?

Comment: If there is a word 'test/batch' in en.txt then it should not be included in the results. exclude.txt file has only words without (hunspell) tags.

Comment: @TLP tried -w parameter. But that does not return correct results because my file contains unicode characters and grep is not fully compatible.

Comment: @shantanuo That might have been rather important information to give in your question. Why would you exclude it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using grep matching whole words:

```
grep -wvf exclude.txt en.txt
```

Explanation (from man grep)

- `-w` `--word-regexp` Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words.
- `-v` `--invert-match`  Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
- `-f` `-f FILE` Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.

Output

```
testing
access/p
batches
cross
```

Comment: tried -w parameter. But that does not return correct results because my file contains unicode characters and grep is not fully compatible. But rg (ripgrep) seems to work as expected. I did not mention about non-latin characters while asking because I did not think it will make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `en.txt` content be

```
test
testing
access/p
batch
batch/n
batches
cross
```

and `exclude.txt` content be

```
test
batch
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"}FNR==NR{arr[$1];next}!($1 in arr)' exclude.txt en.txt
```

gives output

```
testing
access/p
batches
cross
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that `/` is field separator (`FS`), then when processing first file (where number of row globally is equal to number of row inside file, that is `FNR==NR`) I simply use 1st column value as key in array `arr` and then go to `next` line, so nothing other happens, for 2nd (and following files if present) I select lines whose 1st column is not (`!`) one of keys of array `arr`.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 1):

Since there are many words in a dictionary that may have a root in one of those to exclude we cannot conveniently<sup>†</sup> use a look-up hash (built of the exclude list), but have to check all of them.  One way to do that more efficiently is to use an alternation pattern built from the exclude list

```perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Path::Tiny;  # to read ("slurp") a file conveniently

my $excl_file = 'exclude.txt';

my $re_excl = join '|', split /\n/, path($excl_file)->slurp;
$re_excl = qr($re_excl);

while (<>) { 
    if ( m{^ $re_excl (?:/.)? $}x )  {   
        # say "Skip printing (so filter out): $_";
        next;
    }
    say;
}
```

This is used as `program.pl dictionary-filename` and it prints the filtered list.

Here I've assumed that what may follow the root-word to exclude is `/` followed by *one* character, `(?:/.)?`, since examples in the question use that and there is no precise statement on it.  The pattern also assumes no spaces around the word.

Please adjust as/if needed for what may actually follow `/`.  For example, it'd be `(?:/.+)?` for at least one character, `(?:/[np])?` for any character from a specific list (`n` or `p`), `(?:[^xy]+)?` for any characters  *not* in the given list, etc.

The [qr](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) operator forms a proper regex pattern.

---

<sup>†</sup> Can still first strip non-word endings, *then* use a look-up, then put back those endings

```perl
use Path::Tiny;  # to read a file conveniently

my %lu = map { $_ => 1 } path($excl_file)->lines({ chomp => 1 });

while (<>) { 
    chomp;

    # [^\w-] protects hyphenated words (or just use \W)
    # Or: s{(/.+$}{}g;  if "/" is the only possibility
    s/([^\w-].+)$//g;

    next if exists $lu{$_};

    $_ .= $1 if $1; 
    say;
}
```

This will be far more efficient, on large dictionaries and long lists of exclude words.

However, it is far more complex and probably fails some (unstated) requirements